# Defining another level of menu items within a MenuItem ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a list of objects on my WPF window, all having a context menu which allows the user to copy or move items into different panels (so the ItemsSource of the Context menu is this list of panels, and "Copy" and "Move" are sub-menuitems).  However, I have a "CanCopy" property defined in the object that determines whether or not the object can actually be copied.  How can I show/hide this MenuItem depending on the value of this property?  My problem seems to be in defining this variable additional level of MenuItems.

At first I tried something like this, but obviously it's not quite what I'm looking for, since this doubles up the PanelName MenuItem in to two MenuItem containers:

```
<MenuItem Header="Panels..." ItemsSource="{Binding PanelsList}">
    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding PanelName}">
                <MenuItem Header="Copy" Visibility="{Binding CanCopy,Converter={StaticResource BoolToHiddenConverter}}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Move"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Add as Content not ItemTemplate

```
<MenuItem Header="Panels..." ItemsSource="{Binding PanelsList}">
     <MenuItem Header="{Binding PanelName}">
         <MenuItem Header="Copy" Visibility="{Binding CanCopy,Converter={StaticResource BoolToHiddenConverter}}"/>
         <MenuItem Header="Move"/>
     </MenuItem>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't realize you could define the item template like that ... goes to show how much of a WPF beginner I am :)

Comment: Just got a chance to try this out, and this actually isn't working (Oops, should have waited to try this first).  I get a "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource" message.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Ahh, I realize what you want to do, you need to use HiearchicDataTemplate, just like tree but with menues...http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx